# how to change colour of the text entered in label as we enter the desired regular expression in password text field?

Tags: objective-c, uitextfielddelegate

I am new to objective C and I dont know if this can be done without any library or not but if yes kindly let me know...

I have a view in which I have added a button & textfield with some character like "A b # 1 6". Here I need to change the color of characters as I enter the password.
I mean to say when I enter T color or 'A' changes, p is pressed 'b' color changes and so on if I enter special character that color changes and minimum lenth is 6 so when I enter 6 character color of 6 changes.

I tried it with using regular expression but i need this functionality.
for refrence I am adding Image.[image]

I have updated my code instead of labels I have taken Buttons to show the changes. Here is my code:
Now I want to know when user delete character from textfield the color should get back to normal color. I mean if user deletes "A" then button roundButtonCapital should change to normal button.

I hope I am clear. Please let me know if any doubt.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3EymICOjqeNM01zcEQ4eUN0eUk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: To help people to help you edit your question and include minimal code fragments to show what you are doing, what you are stuck on, and what you have tried. Is the password pattern one or multiple images? The image(s) - programmatically produced or resources? How is user typing handled? What have you tried to change the color? Etc. Edit your question (do **not** use comments) to include these details and someone will undoubtedly help you.

Comment: I have added file to- : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3EymICOjqeNM01zcEQ4eUN0eUk/view?usp=sharing.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to know when user delete character from textfield the color should get back to normal color.

At a guess when checking the user input you are only setting the color if the particular condition - uppercase, length, etc. - is met. You should always set the color, to the "passed" color if the condition is met and to the normal color if it is not. Do this on every change to the user input, addition or deletion, and your indicators will always be correct.

**Note**: You did not edit your question to include minimal code fragments, posting a link to a file is no substitute for this. You need to isolate the problem, which is what you should be doing anyway in trying to solve it, show the code for that issue in the question.

In this case you *maybe* could have include the code for a particular test - uppercase, digit, etc. - and explain what it was doing right and what didn't work. *Maybe* here because I don't know my answer is correct, it is a *guess* - to be sure I'd have to scroll through in detail 5 pages of code on a tablet I'm currently typing this on, essentially debug your code and that is not what Stack Overflow is here for.

*You have help people help you, and show you've put effort in, or people just won't be willing to put in effort to help you.*

That said, I hope the guess helps, and stick with SO asking and answering questions!

Comment: the suggestion that you gave about posting a code is helpful. I am new here and still finding out how to post a code. I tried putting my code in blocks but it gave me error. So i posted a link. Sure I will keep this in mind next time. Thanks